# iPad DetailView Design: How prevent the TableViewController header and toolbar to scroll out of the view?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

My iPad app uses a DetailView, which is embedded in a TabBarControl to switch between multiple data views.

The DetailView is designed as **TableViewController**, which has a large header view (to add charts later, the header view makes up approximately 40% of the vertical space) and a toolbar on top.

How can I prevent to scroll the toolbar and header out of the view window when the table has more rows that can be displayed?

I want to have the table rows scrollable but fixed header and toolbar.

What improvement to my design would you suggest?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `UITableViewController`, simply create a subclass of a `UIViewController`. In `viewDidLoad` just add your header views to the `UIViewController`s view and add a `UITableView` below the header views. This way only the `UITableView` scrolls and your header views have a fixed position.

Comment: Thank you, Tom. Would I need to set the tableView delegate and datasource to this new UIViewController?

Comment: Yes, just set the dataSource and the delegate to self within the UIViewController subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Set content inset for tableview like this:

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(offset,0,0,0)];
```

Add ADBannerView programmatically in viewDidLoad. For example:

```
ADBannerView * banner = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
    banner.delegate = self;
    banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, banner.frame.size.width, banner.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:banner];
```

Test.